# How to run a keyboard macro with automator in a background application?

Tags: keyboard, automator

I'm trying to figure out how I can automate a repeating key press within a specific application on automator. Essentially, I want it to run in the background while I'm free to do anything else on my computer.

I'm new to this, so I don't know if it (or anything for that matter) can do what I'm describing

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the specific application is, what you are trying to accomplish and your Mac OS version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done, afaik.

Only the frontmost app will accept keypresses.

I don't have an absolute reference to confirm this, but there are discussion at [Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1117969?start=0&tstart=0), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996334/send-a-key-code-to-an-application-without-activating-it-first) & [MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=29591) that would appear to agree with my belief.

Answer (score -1):

This can easily be done e.g. with python keyboard (https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard).